# Xcode 3.2.5 not creating outlets

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working through various online/book tutorials learning the basics of Xcode.  What is happening is that when I create the IBOutlets and then open Interface builder and try to connect File's Owner to those Outlets (via a button) none of the Outlets appear (except for -View).

I have saved the file and in some cases closed everything and re-opened the file but no luck. In other projects the Outlets appear.  I am using the .xib file to open Interface Builder as stated in the books).

From what I can tell I am not doing anything different when I try to link the Outlets.

Comment: can you post a copy of your code?

Comment: In 'Identity Inspector', have you set the File's Owner to be the class that you made the xib for?